# Can't put into reverse when the engine is running

Tags: transmission, audi

I have a 2004 Audi A4 1.8t. I recently began to have trouble getting into reverse when the engine is running, i can get it sometimes but that requires alot of force. And when i turn off the engine i can easily get into reverse.

What can this be?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your clutch is not disconnecting drive fully, so the reverse gears are not able to mesh.  The synchros on the forward gears are probably putting enough load on the drive to compensate for the problem, therefore you are not experiencing it in the forward gears.

Does the clutch bite very low down on the pedal when releasing?

Comment: Reverse is usually the first place you'll notice when this starts happening. I'd tend to agree with your assessment.

Comment: Sorry for late answer @HandyHowie. The clutch is biting quite high actually

Comment: @noxx It is still a possibility that the clutch is not disengaging fully.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the site!

My gut says that the gear shift linkage is out of adjustment.  On these cars there are cables between the gearbox and gear lever.  From around page 22 onwards of this guide gives you an idea of how to perform the adjustment; https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2597/0906/files/sigmasixinstall.pdf?8650546362459632524

If adjusting the gear linkage doesn't solve the probem it may be that you have worn bushes in the gear linkage in which case installing a replacement bush kit and then performing the linkage adjustment once more ought to remedy the fault.

Comment: Sorry for late answer and thanks! Yeah was my first thought, but when i looked into it, i couldn't see anything. Im no expert but i could so easily get it into reverse when the engine was off. But when i start the engine its h**l of trouble.

Comment: My only other suggestion would be a broken / lose engine mount so that the running engine is moving the gearbox slightly away from where it ought to be.

Comment: Well if that is the case, i have a big problem :(

Comment: @noxx  A faulty engine mount would be a very simple problem to fix.